# How do I store multiple check boxes with local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, local-storage

So, to be honest I am going to have a hard time explaining this so I apologize in advanced.
Basically I am populating a list of checkboxes with the names of cities. using ajax. What I want to do is allow multiple checkboxes to be checked and store each checkbox value in one single key in local storage. I guess it would look something like this as an example in local storage: city: new york,Los Angeles,Miami. I have tried everything I know and I don't even know how to phrase it in google so if anyone could me that would be great. Ill post my code below.

--This is how I am currently populating the checkbox list:

$(document).delegate("#main", "pagecreate", function () {

```
    var citySelect = new Array();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    })
    $.ajax({
        url: 'base_city.php',
        data: '',
        isajax: 1,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var $city_box = $('#city-selector');

            $city_box.empty();

            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {


                $city_box.append("<label for='city_select'><input type='checkbox' name='city_select[]' class='citySelect' value='" + data[i].city + "'>" + data[i].city + "</label>");


            }
        }
    });

});
```

--This is how I am currently storing the values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function filterForm() {
                var cityNames = $('.city_select').attr('value');
                localStorage.setItem("city2",  JSON.stringify(cityNames));
                window.location = "#main";  
                location.reload();

            }


            </script>
```

Comment: You are of course running the filterForm function after the elements are actually inserted into the page and exists? Also jQuery has a neat little ting called .val() --

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
$('.city_select').attr('value');
```

by

```
var arr = [];    
$("input[type=checkbox].city_select:checked").each(function(){arr.push(this.value);});
```

Comment: that didn't didn't seem to work, city just comes up undefined in local storage

Comment: now when I try that, i get this error in javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON